# Comparing objects using the compare method in objective-c

Tags: objective-c

If I were to try and compare two objects in objective-c, I believe as of IOS 6 it is possible to just use normal operators such as == (proof below), however, I would like to know how this would be done with a -compare method.

As far as I know, the compare method works something in this fashion:

```
if ([objOne compare:objTwo] == NSOrderedAscending){
    // objOne is greater
```

First of all, is that correct? And secondly, what are the other comparison methods, I.e, NSOrderedAscending?

[image]

Comment: NSComparisonResult is an enumerated list that contains the following: NSOrderedAscending, NSOrderedSame, and NSOrderedDescending. Refer to   https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Constants/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/NSComparisonResult

Comment: "I believe as of IOS 6 it is possible to just use normal operators such as `==`" - What made you think this? Unless you degrade to C++...

Comment: @H2CO3, The cause for me thinking this, was the fact that it does compile correctly. Edited with screenshot.

Comment: Why are you assigning `NSString` literals to `NSNumber` variables? That's not a good idea. The `==` operator, when used with objects, checks if the two objects reference the same memory pointers. It does not check to see if the two objects represent the same value. For that you must use the `isEqual:` (or its variants).

Comment: @Bernie That's an incorrect logic/deduction. It compiles != it works. `*(int *)0 = 0;` also compiles, yet it segfaults at runtime.

Comment: @H2CO3, the point remains, obj == obj, works correctly, as I stated.

Comment: @Bernie No, it doesn't work. You are being fooled by this trivial case because the compiler is optimizing the two string literals into a single object in memory so your two variables end up pointing to the same object. This is the only reason that `==` is working. NEVER rely on this. It could change. ALWAYS use `isEqual:` to compare two objects for equality.

Comment: @Bernie That's no surprise - `==` still doesn't compare contents but pointers (numerically). If you compare, say, `0x12345` and `0x12345`, which are the same, you'll get that they are the same.

Comment: @rmaddy, Firstly, I am not assigning NSString literals to NSNumber variables, an update in objective-c means that instead of having to alloc and init an NSNumber, NSDictionary or NSArray, you can simply use @"<number>" instead, saving a lot of code. Secondly, That simply isn't true anymore (it used to be) as my screenshot shows. The memory addresses of numberOne and numberTwo are completely different, and this is checking the values of the objects. Try it for yourself. http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html

Comment: @Bernie `@"1"` is an `NSString` literal. What you want is `@1`. That gives you an `NSNumber` object. Also, your screen shot tells nothing about the memory address of the objects. And it's not the memory address of the two variables, it the memory address that they point to that matters.

Comment: @Bernie, see my post for a screenshot that proves you wrong.

Comment: @rmaddy, as for the first part, you were correct, I apologise, I modified my code and screenshot a few minutes ago.

Comment: @Bernie Do you have any idea how much code would break if the semantics of the `==` operator changed when used with pointers. There is no way that it changed.

Comment: @rmaddy, edited with screenshot of working example which is not checking memory addresses but values.

Comment: @rmaddy, I was still in the process of editing, memory addresses included.

Comment: @Bernie You didn't read my earlier comment about compiler optimization. You are being fooled. The two `@1` literals are being optimized into one. So both variables point to the same object. Therefore the `==` operator (which is comparing the pointers, not the values), just happens to appear to work. Don't be fooled.

Comment: @Bernie You are logging the address of variables. This is completely different than the memory address that each variable points to. It is the latter that matters. It is the latter that is compared with the `==` operator. The address of the actual variable is irrelevant.

Comment: @Bernie Run that latest test app again but instead of entering a number between 0 and 12, enter a large number like 12345. What do you get? The `NSNumber` class returns constants for the numbers 0 through 12 (or so).

Comment: @Rmaddy, Hmmmmm, I think I see where I've made an issue, I'll get back to you. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

the writer of a class is resposible for comparing, meaning you have to define when two objects are equal.

This is done by defining a method `compare:`, that should return either NSOrderedAscending, NSOrderedDescending, NSOrderedSame

From the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Constants/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/NSComparisonResult)

> **NSComparisonResult**
>
> These constants are used to indicate how items in a request are
>   ordered.
>
> ```
> enum {
>    NSOrderedAscending = -1,
>    NSOrderedSame,
>    NSOrderedDescending
> };
> typedef NSInteger NSComparisonResult;
> ```

Note, that nothing stops you from creating other methods that return those NSComparisionResults. iE NSString has `compare:` and `caseInsensitiveCompare:`

`==` will just check for identity: if the pointers are the same, this will return true, while if there are to different objects but that are the same in mening of the same properties, it will still return false.

---

From **[NSComparisonMethods Protocol Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSComparisonMethods_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)**

> The default implementation provided for many of these methods by NSObject is appropriate for objects that implement a single comparison method whose selector, signature, and description match the following:
>
> ```
> - (NSComparisonResult)compare:(id)object;
> ```
>
> This method should return NSOrderedAscending if the receiver is less
>   than object, NSOrderedDescending if the receiver is greater than
>   object, and NSOrderedSame if the receiver and object are equal. For
>   example, NSString does not implement most of the methods declared in
>   this informal protocol, but NSString objects still handle messages
>   conforming to this protocol properly because NSString implements a
>   compare: method that meets the necessary requirements. Cocoa also
>   includes appropriate compare: method implementations for the NSDate,
>   NSDecimalNumber, and NSValue classes.

This means that if you provided a `-compare:` method, you can also use `-isEqual:`.

```
if ([objOne isEqual:objTwo]){ //…
```

---

[image]